# Visual studio additional include directories with network path

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Does Visual Studio (2008/2010) support network paths as `additional include directories`?
I tried to add a network path, but looks it doesn't work. Any idea?

My network path is as this `\\192.168.1.135\win_libs\boost_1_47_0`

Comment: have you tried mapping that server folder to a drive letter. like, `net use w: \\192.168.1.135\win_libs`. then use the drive letter in the search path.

Answer (score 0):

Check under Project Properties and settings for the compiler.  The Additional Include Directories are specified under the compiler tab in there.  If you are already connected to the specified location, you should be able to include directories from there.

Comment: You mean VS supports network paths as Additional Include Directories?

Comment: It should, I have never tried it myself but if you are connected, there is no reason why it should not.

Comment: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp': No such file or directory`. But if I add boost inside my PC it works fine. I suspect, VS may not support network parths?

Comment: Can I assume that the complete path to the include file is: `\\192.168.1.135\win_libs\boost_1_47_0\boost\smart_ptr\scoped_ptr.hpp` and your additional include directory is specified as: `\\192.168.1.135\win_libs\boost_1_47_0`?  Also, your include file is specified as `#include <boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp>`?

Comment: yep, thats how I added

Comment: Have you tried to use the suggestion by @Cheers and hth. - Alf on mapping the drive to a letter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45080/discussion-between-unxnut-and-nayana-adassuriya)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can **NOT** directly add the network path to your project!

However, one way to work through is you first map this network path to your PC (by clicking `Map Network Drive` in `Computer`) first and then add this mapped driver path to the project.